# convert my user defined string into char array in java

Tags: type-conversion

I have string as below in java , when i am  trying to convert getting error
HelloWorld.java:12: error: array required, but String found
c[i]=s[i];
^
1 error

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    String s="Abcde";
    char c[];
    
    System.out.print(s);
    
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        //
        c[i]=s[i];
    }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I would suggest you to use inbuilt function instead of doing this. You can 
find many methods available on internet and tutorials to convert your 
string into char array in java. for example- Using **toCharArray()** Method.
```

`public static void main(String args[])
{

```
    String str = "Abcde";

    // Creating array and Storing the array
    // returned by toCharArray()
    char[] ch = str.toCharArray();

    // Printing array
    for (char c : ch) {
        System.out.println(c);
    }`
```

Comment: Thanks Suraj for quick response ,HelpFull